# How to flip/reverse a 2D array's rows or columns using STL

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, multidimensional-array, stl

I have a 2D array of arbitrary type, of dimensions `N x M` (i.e., `T array[N][M];`) e.g.,

[image]

that I want flip it either its **columns** e.g.,

[image]

or its **rows** e.g.,

[image]

How can I do this easily just using STL?

Comment: One way to do this is set a flag in a class that wraps the matrix and when you reverse, switch this flag. When accessing an element through a getter function, change the index calculation accordingly. This is fast if you swap often. However the cost to access each element is slightly higher due to the extra flag.

Comment: Also the answer depends on how you represent the data. Is it encoded in 1 flat array, or an array of arrays, etc?

Comment: @NeilKirk A 2d array (e.g., `T a[4][3]`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do this just by using [`std::reverse`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse).

Below I'm defining two generic functions namely `flip_columns` and `flip_rows` that take as input a 2D array of arbitrary type and they flip/reverse its columns and rows respectively.

### Flip/Reverse 2D Array Columns

```
template<typename T, std::size_t N, std::size_t M>
void flip_columns(T (&arr)[N][M]) {
  std::for_each(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr),
                [](auto &i) {std::reverse(std::begin(i), std::end(i));});
}
```

### Flip/Reverse 2D Array Rows

```
template<typename T, std::size_t N, std::size_t M>
void flip_rows(T (&arr)[N][M]) {
  std::reverse(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr));
}
```

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e59482936f696f30)

Answer (score 2):

There's **no need to move stuff in memory**. A typical approach would define a **traversal policy** that 'travels' the array in the specified order (reversed columns or reversed rows) which is particularly efficient for really large objects that we don't want to mess with.

Showcasing this, the helper below "reverses" both rows and columns at the same time :

```
template<typename T, std::size_t N, std::size_t K>
struct Rev
{
    T(&data)[N][K];
    Rev(T(&data)[N][K]) : val(val) { }
    T& access(std::size_t row, std::size_t column) {
        return val[N - row - 1][K - column - 1];
    }
};
```

example :

```
int ar[2][5] = { { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }, { 11, 22, 33, 44, 55 } };

Rev<int, 2, 5> ob(ar);
std::cout << ob.access(1, 3); // prints 2
```

I opted for an `access` method since customizing `operator[]` would require returning an indexable temporary object and that takes a few more lines to be as efficient as the reference wrapper shown here; anyhow its doable in a way that matches the interface of a built in array, ie :

```
Rev<int, 2, 5> ob(ar)
ob[1][3];
```

In the same spirit, **reverse iterators** could be used to loop through slices of the array (rows or columns)

Answer (score -1):

In 2d vector

to rotate rows we use -> reverse(a[i].begin,a[i].end());

to rotate columns we use -> reverse(a.begin(),a.end());

Comment: OP is not using `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`, he is using a 2-D C-style array.